# RUBY Pushing array into array overwrites all previous elements?

Tags: arrays, ruby, push

This function reads a file and inserts the data into a multi-dimensional array, however it seems that on every push of temp into $table, it completely overwrites every element in $table with what is in temp.

```
def self.read_file
i = 0
j = 0
$table = []
$n = 0
temp = []

first_line = true

IO.foreach("data.dat") do |line|
  data = line.split
  if first_line
    $n = data[0].to_i
    first_line = false
    puts('Read first line')
    puts $n
 else
   while (j < $n)
     temp[j] = data[j].to_i
     j = j + 1
   end
   $table << temp
   i = i + 1
   j = 0
  end
p $table
end

end
```

Can anyone explain this behavior and help me debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have edited your method. It should work.

```
   def self.read_file
       i = 0
       j = 0
      table = []
       n = 0
     first_line = true
     IO.foreach("data.dat") do |line|
       temp=[]
       data = line.split
       if first_line
        n = data[0].to_i
       first_line = false
       puts('Read first line')
      puts n
   else
      while (j < n)
         temp[j] = data[j].to_i
          j = j + 1
       end
    table << temp
     i = i + 1
      j = 0
   end
    p table
  end
 end
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please at least describe the change you made, or post only the relevant part of the code.

Comment: I think issue was in temp so I have just change the place of temp variable  with in do loop